# Powershell or cmd to get filetime/windowstime of a file in windows?

Tags: windows, powershell, filetime

I think I have gotten myself confused here, I'm trying to get the creation time of a file on windows machine and convert this to windowstime, which I think is actually filetime?

Looking at this seems to tell me differently https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms725496(v=vs.85).aspx

Is filetime the same as windows time?

The aim is to have a powershell or bat script to show the filetime/windows time of that file when it was created.

Any pointers would be grand

Thanks

Comment: Windows time is a relative time that is not meaningful for files. In particular, it cannot represent times before the system started. Why do you need a file creation time in Windows time format?

Comment: I've got files being stored with this type of perfix 01cf83cdb2922d76 which I think is the windows timestamp?

Comment: Unlikely. If true, it would mean that your system has been running without a reboot for over 4 million years.